# Efficient saving of Android AdMob interstitials

Tags: android, admob

Scenario:
Activity A initializes and loads an AdMob interstitial. Then Activity B starts on top of A, which can cause A to be destroyed to reclaim resources.
When the user comes back to Activity A, it needs to be recreated and the interstitial downloaded again.

What is the best way to preserve a downloaded interstitial?

The method `onSaveInstanceState` seems to be unsuitable for this.

Comment: AFAIK, you should recreate interstitial in onResume() of Activity A

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to have a single Activity and to use 2 Fragments within that Activity. That way your interstitial never get destroyed.